# How a variable can be recognized from button to method?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to count the number of words and characters in a specific text. Now this all works fine but I want to tidy up code so that I don't have to include the the you see under `newSummaryMethod()` into every button, hence why I have placed it in it's own method. But when I do this, it doesn't count the words and characters. Now I know the reason is that `string copyText = "";` in the method, that's because if I don't declare that string variable, then I will get syntax errors in my button that `copyText` is not declared.

My question is really about how can I get the `newSummaryMethod` to know that it needs to communication with the `copyText` in first the vowels button? I have another button where `copyText` may behave a bit differently so I think I need the button to communicate with the method.

```
 private void newSummaryMethod() {
     string copyText = "";

     /*Count number of lines in processed text,
extra line is always counted so -1 brings it to correct number*/
     int numLines = copyText.Split('\n').Length - 1;

     //seperate certain characters in order to find words
     char[] seperator = (" " + nl).ToCharArray();

     //number of words, characters and include extra line breaks variable
     int numberOfWords = copyText.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
     int numberOfChar = copyText.Length - numLines;

     //Unprocessed Summary
     newSummary = nl + "Word Count: " + numberOfWords + nl + "Characters Count: " + numberOfChar;
 }

 private void btnVowels_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     //Strip vowels
     string vowels = "AaEeIiOoUu";
     string copyText = richTextBox1.Text;
     copyText = new string(copyText.Where(c => !vowels.Contains(c)).ToArray());

     newSummaryMethod();

     //Write into richTextBox2
     wholeText = richTextBox1.Text + oldSummary + copyText + newSummary;
     Write(Second_File, wholeText);
     richTextBox2.Text = wholeText;
 }

 private void btnAlpha_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

     //Remove non alpha characters
     string nonAlpha = @"[^A-Za-z ]+";
     string addSpace = "";
     string copyText = richTextBox1.Text;
     copyText = Regex.Replace(copyText, nonAlpha, addSpace);

     newSummaryMethod();

     //Write into richTextBox2
     wholeText = richTextBox1.Text + oldSummary + copyText + nl + newSummary;
     Write(Second_File, wholeText);
     richTextBox2.Text = wholeText;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass the data the method needs to it as an argument

```
private void newSummaryMethod(string copyText) {...}
```

and then call it like

```
newSummaryMethod(copyText);
```

another way is declaring your variable outside the function scope so both functions will have access to it.

```
string copyText = null;  //added


private void newSummaryMethod() {
     copyText = ""; //changed

     /*Count number of lines in processed text,
extra line is always counted so -1 brings it to correct number*/
     int numLines = copyText.Split('\n').Length - 1;

     //seperate certain characters in order to find words
     char[] seperator = (" " + nl).ToCharArray();

     //number of words, characters and include extra line breaks variable
     int numberOfWords = copyText.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
     int numberOfChar = copyText.Length - numLines;

     //Unprocessed Summary
     newSummary = nl + "Word Count: " + numberOfWords + nl + "Characters Count: " + numberOfChar;
 }

 private void btnVowels_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     //Strip vowels
     string vowels = "AaEeIiOoUu";
     copyText = richTextBox1.Text; //changed
     copyText = new string(copyText.Where(c => !vowels.Contains(c)).ToArray());

     newSummaryMethod();

     //Write into richTextBox2
     wholeText = richTextBox1.Text + oldSummary + copyText + newSummary;
     Write(Second_File, wholeText);
     richTextBox2.Text = wholeText;
 }

 private void btnAlpha_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

     //Remove non alpha characters
     string nonAlpha = @"[^A-Za-z ]+";
     string addSpace = "";
     copyText = richTextBox1.Text; //changed
     copyText = Regex.Replace(copyText, nonAlpha, addSpace);

     newSummaryMethod();

     //Write into richTextBox2
     wholeText = richTextBox1.Text + oldSummary + copyText + nl + newSummary;
     Write(Second_File, wholeText);
     richTextBox2.Text = wholeText;

 }
```